# Pipeline support with BinaryJedis

Tags: redis, jedis

I am using BinaryJedis to store and retrieve data as I am dealing with raw data. With Jedis pipeline I am able to save data in byte[] form in redis list. But when I try to retrieve this list data (one entry) using "lindex", I dont find any interface for this, i.e. lindex takes byte[] as input but returns Response

```
public Response<String> lindex(byte[] key, int index) {
    client.lindex(key, index);
    return getResponse(BuilderFactory.STRING);
}
```

Why there is no interface that returns Response

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Are you looking for a byte[] response or you wonder how to use Response<>?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for Response byte[] output.